# AngularJS - Not update table-pagination after http-get success's event

Tags: angularjs

i have a problem. I'm using AngularJs with WebService-Rest, and can't update some table after the call HTTP-GET to WebService. I did tested everything but i can't get it. 
Next, i attach the code. Thanks!

HTML:
...

```
<div class="row" ng-app="SIGA" ng-controller="CreateTable">           
     <div class="container-fluid">  
       <table class="table table-striped">  
         <tbody>  
           <tr>  
             <td>Buscar</td>  
             <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.nombre" /></td>                   
           </tr>  
           <tr ng-repeat="e in estaciones | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">  
             <td>  
               <button class="btn">  
                 Detalle  
               </button>  
             </td>  
             <td>{{e.nombre}}</td>                   
           </tr>  
         </tbody>  
       </table>  
       <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
             max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
             items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
       </pagination>
     </div> 
</div>
```

...

JS: ...

```
app.controller('RestEstacion', function ($rootScope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/sigarest/webresources/entity.estaciones').
    success(function(data) {
       $rootScope.estaciones = data;         UpdateTable($rootScope);                                                
    }).
error(function(status) {
    alert('error:'+status);
});            
});

app.controller('CreateTable', function ($scope,$rootScope) {  
   $rootScope.predicate = 'nombre';  
   $rootScope.reverse = true;  
   $rootScope.currentPage = 1;  
   $rootScope.order = function (predicate) {  
     $rootScope.reverse = ($rootScope.predicate === predicate) ? !$rootScope.reverse : false;  
     $rootScope.predicate = predicate;  
   };  
   $rootScope.estaciones =  [];
   $rootScope.totalItems = $rootScope.estaciones.length;
   $rootScope.numPerPage = 5;  
   $rootScope.paginate = function (value) {  
     var begin, end, index;  
     begin = ($rootScope.currentPage - 1) * $rootScope.numPerPage;  
     end = begin + $rootScope.numPerPage;  
     index = $rootScope.estaciones.indexOf(value);  
     return (begin <= index && index < end);  
   };  

 });
```

JS (Update Function):

```
   function UpdateTable($rootScope){            
   $rootScope.totalItems = $rootScope.estaciones.length;}
```

Comment: Have you done a console.log on the success data to verify that it is actually returning a response?

Comment: Hi Daniel, i successfully receive data from the call. The problem is that the pagination not update when i click next/last or any page's number. I can show the first page well but not work to other pages.

Comment: When you say the pagination does not update, do you mean the table contents do update, and it is only the pagination footer at the bottom that is not changing to the new index?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the scope. I have 2 controllers, one to create the table (first run without content model) and the second the call to the Web service. I had to assign the result of the call on "json" format to a range of type "rootScope" to update in the vacuum from the second controller model. The problem is that updates the pages (only the contents of the first).
Is it correct to have two drivers in this situation ?, or should have a single controller with two functions and manage one "scope" ?. Thank you

Comment: Using $rootScope as a bridge is a sign that you need to move most of this logic out of the controller and into a service that any number of controllers can reference. The service should make the API call and cache the data. It should manage the pagination as well. Then a (single) controller should reference the service to find out what data to display at the current time. If you bind the controller's scope to a variable in the service, the view will then have access to everything (including changes) in that service variable.

Comment: Also, are you making a new API call on every pagination change? The code above looks like a single API call for all table data.

Answer (score 1):

** Original Answer (what comments refer to) **

I think you are assigning the get response object rather than the data inside it. Try this:

```
   success(function(response) {
       $rootScope.estaciones = response.data;         
       UpdateTable($rootScope);                                                
    }).
```

** EDIT **

Now that we have established that you are returning data from the API, the real issue appears to be the double controller using $rootScope as a bridge, which can work but is a bit of an anti-pattern in Angular.

The first controller in your app is trying to act like a service, and so really needs to be converted into one. Here is some **SAMPLE PSUEDO CODE** to give the idea. I do not fully understand your code, like the pagination directive. There should be a click handler in the pagination directive that would call the service method changePagination and pass in the new page number. There should be no need for $rootScope anywhere in this.

JS

```
app.service('RestEstacionService', function ($http) {
  var RestEstacionService = this;
  this.apiData = null;
  this.tableData = null;
  this.currentPage = 1;
  this.numPerPage = 5;
  this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/sigarest/webresources/entity.estaciones';

  this.getData = function (url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        RestEstacionService.apiData = response.data;
        // do success stuff here
        // figure out which page the view should display
        // assign a portion of the api data to the tableData variable
      })
  };

  this.changePagination = function (newPage) {
    // do your your pagination work here
  };

});


app.controller('RestEstacionController', ['$scope', 'RestEstacionService', function ($scope, RestEstacionService) {
  $scope.service = RestEstacionService;
  RestEstacionService.getData(RestEstacionService.url);
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-app="SIGA" ng-controller="RestEstacionController">           
 <div class="container-fluid">  
   <table class="table table-striped">  
     <tbody>  
       <tr>  
         <td>Buscar</td>  
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.nombre" /></td>                   
       </tr>  
       <tr ng-repeat="row in services.tableData | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">  
         <td>  
           <button class="btn">  
             Detalle  
           </button>  
         </td>  
         <td>{{row.nombre}}</td>                   
       </tr>  
     </tbody>  
   </table>  
   <pagination total-items="services.apiData.length" ng-model="services.currentPage"  
         max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
         items-per-page="services.numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
   </pagination>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That's not the problem. I successfully receive data from the HTTP call, the problem is the page of the table. The table shows the first page with data but to move from page does not refresh the table.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!!!! I solved the problem. This was related to the scope , having two different drivers each driving a different scope. Thanks you. Now, i have a new problema, when I want to search only searches the current page. I test the original example and it is the same. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What I would do is write a service method that searches the original api data rather than the current table model. That method should then return an array of matches that replace the current table model.